# Is there a .NET library which will give me the ability to run awk scripts in a .NET environment?

Tags: .net, awk

I am migrating a some functionality off a unix system onto a Microsoft stack.

The old system makes use of awk scripts to reformat files.

Is there a library (or other mechanism) which will run under .NET and can understand the awk scripts?

Comment: did you find anything yet? Looking myself...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `awk` that comes with [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and invoke it using [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, @Oded.  That's sneaky thinking! Unfortunately, I really need something that is naitive .NET.

Comment: @AJ. - I've looked around and didn't find any managed awk implementation.